# Query a document and all of its subdocuments that match a condition in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB storing data from different sensors.
It has the following structure:

```
 {
     "_id" : 1,
     "sensorName" : "Heart Rate",
     "samplePeriod" : 1000,
     "data" : [
             {
                 "timestamp" : NumberLong("1483537204046"),
                 "dataPoints" : [ 68 70 ]
             },
             {
                 "timestamp" : NumberLong("1483537206046"),
                 "dataPoints" : [ 68 70 ]
             }
     ]
}
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "sensorName" : "Ambient Light",
    "samplePeriod" : 500,
    "data" : [
            {
                "timestamp" : NumberLong("1483537204058"),
                "dataPoints" : [ 56, 54, 54, 54 ]
            },
            {
                "timestamp" : NumberLong("1483537206058"),
                "dataPoints" : [ 56, 54, 54, 54 ]
            }
    ]
}
```

Now for example i need the "Heart Rate" - document with all of its fields and those of its "data" - subdocuments matching the condition "timestamp between 1483537204000 and 1483537214000".

I know about aggregation but cant figure out, how to not only return the matching subdocuments but to return the whole "Heart Rate" - document containing only the matching subdocuments in "data".

Is my structure efficient at all? Do you have any hint for a better structure for efficient querying for such data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like below.

$match to keep the heart rate record.

$filter to filter the subdocument with the condition.

$project to display the results.

```
aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "_id": 1
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "_id": 1,
        "sensorName": 1,
        "samplePeriod": 1,
        "data": {
            "$filter": {
                "input": "$data",
                "as": "result",
                "cond": {
                    $and: [{
                        $gte: ["$$result.timestamp", 1483537204000]
                    }, {
                        $lte: ["$$result.timestamp", 1483537214000]
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you.
Is there any way to do this in java spring?